# How to replace a single value in a list of data frames

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of data frames as follows:

```
dat_1 <- data.frame(x = c("A", "B", "C", "D") %>% as.factor)
dat_2 <- data.frame(x = c("A", "B", "C", "D") %>% as.character)
dat <- list("dat_1" = dat_1, "dat_2" = dat_2)
```

Some columns are factors and other are characters. I need to replace any instance of "C" with NA for all data frames in the list. How would I accomplish this?

I know I can accomplish this using the following code, but I want to avoid hardcoding each data frame in the list if possible:

```
dat[["dat_2"]][dat[["dat_2"]] == "C"] <- NA
```

Comment: Maybe this too: `lapply(dat, sapply,function(x) replace(x,x=="C",NA))`. Uses `sapply` for potentially more columns. `lapply`-`replace` might be sufficient. Or with `dplyr` and `purrr` : `dat %>% 
  purrr::map(~replace(.x,.x=="C",NA))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the way you created the data frame will cause the columns of the data frames to be all factor. I modified your code as follows to make the first data frame to be factor and the second data frame to be character.

```
dat_1 <- data.frame(x = c("A", "B", "C", "D"))
dat_2 <- data.frame(x = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dat <- list("dat_1" = dat_1, "dat_2" = dat_2)
```

We can use the following code to replace all "C" to be `NA`.

```
dat2 <- lapply(dat, function(x){
  x[] <- lapply(x, function(x) replace(x, x %in% "C", NA))
  return(x)
})

dat2
# $dat_1
#      x
# 1    A
# 2    B
# 3 <NA>
# 4    D
# 
# $dat_2
#      x
# 1    A
# 2    B
# 3 <NA>
# 4    D
```

The code will not change the column types.

```
lapply(dat2, function(x) sapply(x, class))
# $dat_1
#        x 
# "factor" 
# 
# $dat_2
#           x 
# "character"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
lapply(dat, function (x) {sapply(x, function (y) {y <- as.character(y); y[which(y == "C")] <- NA; return (y)})})
```

Comment: Could you explain this a bit?

Answer (score 2):

We can use `dplyr::recode`

```
library(dplyr)
purrr::map(dat, . %>% mutate_all(~recode(., "C"=NA_character_)))

#$dat_1
#     x
#1    A
#2    B
#3 <NA>
#4    D

#$dat_2
#     x
#1    A
#2    B
#3 <NA>
#4    D
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `na_if`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map(dat, ~ .x %>%
             mutate_all(na_if, "C"))
#$dat_1
#     x
#1    A
#2    B
#3 <NA>
#4    D

#$dat_2
#     x
#1    A
#2    B
#3 <NA>
#4    D
```